# getJson method returns an error using woocommerce JSON API plugin

Tags: api, jquery, jquery-mobile, wordpress

I'm using woocommerce JSON API to retrieve the data of some products like price, SKU, etc...
The thing is that I get an error using this API. I've installed the plugin succesfully and activated it in the WordPress Dashboard.
I've tried the example given in GitHub exactly as the author says.
Here's my javascript code:

```
    $(document).on('pageinit','#restau' ,function(){

    var url = 'http://danielvivancos.com/edu/wordpress/shop/?callback=?';
    params = { action: 'woocommerce_json_api', proc:"get_products"};
    params.arguments = {token: 1234, per_page: 2, page: 1}
    jQuery.getJSON(url,params).done(function (data) { 
        alert("success");
        console.log(data);
        console.log(url);
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
});
```

At first it didn't do anything, and I didn't understand what was happening but then I added the `.error()` function and it threw me an error...

Here http://danielvivancos.com/edu/directebre_app_jquerymobile/ you will find the three alerts displayed when you click on any of the three products.

Hope someone can help me or give me some ideas to solve it.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

The API Almost always returns some kind of error string and error code. The one time when it wouldn't would be if there was a PHP error (Even then it tries to catch the error and return something).

One thing you may need to do is to visit the users settings page, setup your permissions, and then save the settings for that API User. Whenever a new method is added to the API you will have to visit this page and resave it.

Another thing to do is to try and run `php tests/get_products.php` and see what happens. Most of the API functions have a tests file that you can run from the command line to test the API.

Also, while I am very happy you are using it :) it is still unfinished and in the early stages of development.

It looks like your example is working though?

Could you post a bit more about what error you are getting?

When I click on one of the items, it takes me to a page where a popup shows up with a bunch of HTML, this normally means that your API page is not setup properly (if it is making an api request). You will need to setup the API page ( Just create a wordpress page, or use an existing one) Then in the WooCom menu select JSON Api, and set the API page from the dropdown list. Remember to save.

Comment: I've already set up the permissions but what am I supposed to write in IPS ALLOWED? I've also set the Woocommerce JSON API as the API PAGE. But my app keeps throwing this html popup. On the other hand, `php tests/get_products.php`throws the following error:       Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /usr/home/danielvivancos.com/web/edu/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-json-api-master/tests/get_products.php on line 14
Result is: